how to access phone location in Android app using Kotlin
My app runs on a private network in a remote location, so I'm really only interested in GPS coordinate, not WiFi assisted, but using the google play services integrated function is ok too. The rest of the app is using Jetpack Compose for graphics and it's done except for a user input box that I'd like to fill in with the current location as a default value. The user can change this.
I downloaded and tried several online examples. Most did not compile. I finally typed in some code by following along with a YouTube video. That came really close and I extracted the embedded graphics, fixed it so it compiles, runs, and works with restrictions. I'm going to try to attach the resulting code..
The remaining problem is that the location acquisition code and the graphics are both inside the MainActivity and I don't know enough about Kotlin and its scoping and referencing rules to figure out how to separate them. If I put the graphics code elsewhere, I can't call getCurrentLocationMine(). If I try to pull the location acquisition code out of MainActivity and put in the ViewModel, where I'd like it to live, I can't figure out how to supply the required Activity argument to the functions which is currently handled with "this" from inside MainActivity.
So, any of the following answers would be helpful:

How to properly call a function defined in MainActivity from elsewhere

How to supply the Activity argument to functions such as ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission from inside a ViewModel

Some other way to get the location of the phone


As you can tell, I don't really know what I'm doing with Kotlin. I've gotten this far, (I have multiple ViewModels acquiring data from external sources, displaying the data and allowing user updates from multiple integrated screen), by imitating other code. But this has me stumped.
The following is more how I would like the code to be arranged, but does not compile because there is not a valid Activity or Context parameter, I think. At least I don't know where to get them.
package com.example.currentlocationtutorial

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
//import android.widget.TextView
//import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.currentlocationtutorial.ui.theme.CurrentLocationTutorialTheme
import com.example.yo.Greeting
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices



fun locationPrint(lat:Double, lon:Double):String {
    return "%.6f".format(lat)+" "+"%.6f".format(lon)
}

//
// In this code example I have put the phone location access code in this ViewModel.
// I like segregating the data access code from the graphics like this and, big plus, I know
// how to get the data from the ViewModel anywhere else I need it for computation or display.
// Unfortunately this code does not compile, because the Activity or Context parameter
// needed for many of the functions is no longer available. 
// "this" of course references the ViewModel and not the original MainActivity. 
// Also the functions startActivity() and
// getSystemService() are no longer defined which I don't understand. Android Studio suggests
// importing ContextCompat.startActivity() and ContextCompat.getSystemService().
//
class DataModel: ViewModel() {
    var stext by mutableStateOf("just started")
    var ltext by mutableStateOf("Unknown")
    var lstatus=false
    var lcount=0
    var ntry=0
    var nrequest=0
    //
    // in the following line and several others "this" is the wrong type of object
    // it needs to be an Activity not a ViewModel
    //
    var fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    fun getCurrentLocationMine() {
        ntry++
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {
                //final latitude and longitude here
                //
                // I think this check is superfluous, already done in checkPermissions(),
                // but Android Studio really wanted to put it here, so I let it.
                //
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return
                }
                fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    val location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                        lstatus = false
                        stext = "null returned"
                    } else {
                        lstatus = true
                        stext = "got location"
                        lcount++
                        ltext = locationPrint(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // setting open here
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            // request permission here
            stext = "requesting permission"
            requestPermission()
            stext = "requested permission"
        }

    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        nrequest++
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ), PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION
        )
    }

    //
    // I don't know what this is. It came with the original example.
    //
    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION = 100
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            stext = "permission granted"
            return true
        } else {
            stext = "permission denied"
            return false
        }
    }
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    val dmodel: DataModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            //
            // get location once here to get things started
            //
            dmodel.getCurrentLocationMine()

            CurrentLocationTutorialTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting(dmodel)
                }
            }
        }


    }
}

//
// I'd like to pull the graphics out like this, because I really want to merge the location on
// a screen that includes data drawn from several other ViewModel. Will also be doing
// computations with the phone location and several other variables to help the user orient
// themselves and find things. Don't need help with these things, I know how to do this.
// I would call getCurrentLocationMine() before presenting this screen, not from a button
// push as it is done in this code. I know how to do this if the location access code is moved into
// the ViewModel as I'd like to do above.
//
@Composable
fun Greeting(dmodel: DataModel) {
    val modifier: Modifier = Modifier

    Surface(color = Color.Blue,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(4.dp)) {
        Column() {
            Row() {
                Text(
                    text = "Does this get current location??????",
                    modifier = modifier
                )
            }
            Row() {
                val stext2 = dmodel.stext
                val showstext = "Status: $stext2"
                Text(
                    text = showstext,
                    modifier = modifier
                )
            }
            Row() {
                val stext2 =
                    dmodel.lcount.toString() + " " + dmodel.ntry.toString() + " " + dmodel.nrequest.toString()
                val showstext = "Count: $stext2"
                Text(
                    text = showstext,
                    modifier = modifier
                )
            }
            Row() {
                val ltext2 = dmodel.ltext
                val showltext = "Location: $ltext2"
                Text(
                    text = showltext,
                    modifier = modifier
                )
            }
            Row() {
                OutlinedButton(
                    onClick = { dmodel.getCurrentLocationMine() },
                )
                { Text(text = "Compute") }
            }
        }
    }
}

This is the code that does compile and work but doesn't give me access to the function getCurrentLocationMine() where I need it elsewhere in the project.
package com.example.currentlocationtutorial

import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
//import android.widget.TextView
//import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.currentlocationtutorial.ui.theme.CurrentLocationTutorialTheme
import com.example.yo.Greeting
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices



fun locationPrint(lat:Double, lon:Double):String {
    return "%.6f".format(lat)+" "+"%.6f".format(lon)
}


class DataModel: ViewModel() {
    var stext by mutableStateOf("just started")
    var ltext by mutableStateOf("Unknown")
    var lstatus=false
    var lcount=0
    var ntry=0
    var nrequest=0

    fun update() {
    }

    fun get(){
//        MainActivity.getCurrentLocation();
    }
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    val dmodel: DataModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            dmodel.update();                // this is only executed once, i think

            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

            CurrentLocationTutorialTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting(dmodel)
                    getCurrentLocationMine()
                }
            }
        }


    }

    fun getCurrentLocationMine() {
        dmodel.ntry++
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {
                //final latitude and longitude here
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return
                }
                fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    val location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                         dmodel.lstatus = false
                        dmodel.stext = "null returned"
                    } else {
                        dmodel.lstatus = true
                        dmodel.stext = "got location"
                        dmodel.lcount++
                        dmodel.ltext = locationPrint(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                    }
                }
            } else {
                // setting open here
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            // request permission here
            dmodel.stext = "requesting permission"
            requestPermission()
            dmodel.stext = "requested permission"
        }

    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        dmodel.nrequest++
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ), PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION
        )
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION = 100
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            dmodel.stext = "permission granted"
            return true
        } else {
            dmodel.stext = "permission denied"
            return false
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun Greeting(dmodel: DataModel) {
        val modifier: Modifier = Modifier

        Surface(color = Color.Blue,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(4.dp)) {
            Column() {
                Row() {
                    Text(
                        text = "Does this get current location??????",
                        modifier = modifier
                    )
                }
                Row() {
                    val stext2 = dmodel.stext
                    val showstext = "Status: $stext2"
                    Text(
                        text = showstext,
                        modifier = modifier
                    )
                }
                Row() {
                    val stext2 =
                        dmodel.lcount.toString() + " " + dmodel.ntry.toString() + " " + dmodel.nrequest.toString()
                    val showstext = "Count: $stext2"
                    Text(
                        text = showstext,
                        modifier = modifier
                    )
                }
                Row() {
                    val ltext2 = dmodel.ltext
                    val showltext = "Location: $ltext2"
                    Text(
                        text = showltext,
                        modifier = modifier
                    )
                }
                Row() {
                    OutlinedButton(
                        onClick = { getCurrentLocationMine() },
                    )
                    { Text(text = "Compute") }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

